# Prevent Zend from translating validate message

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-validate, zend-translate

I have a custom Zend validator. This validator will run an external program that returns an error message in `printf` format together with an arguments-array.

I have a message template for messages from this external program:

```
const MSG_IMPORTER_ERROR = 'importerError';
```

In my `isValid`-function in my custom Validator I do the following:

```
// $err contains the error from the external program
$this->setMessage(
    vsprintf($v->translate($err['template']), $err['args']),
    self::MSG_IMPORTER_ERROR
);
$this->_error(self::MSG_IMPORTER_ERROR);
return false;
```

Since Zend runs the message through translation, I will have the already translated text translated again. I wish to avoid this. So my question is:

*How do I disable translation of validation message?*

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. Validator translation is simply deactivated by adding the below code inside the validator when setting the message to a pre-translated message:

```
$this->setDisableTranslator(true);
```

Silly that I missed that one.